# Is there a simple way to bind a property of one xaml object to another?

Tags: xaml, binding

I have a stackpanel with two images in it, it starts out with one image hidden and the other visible. My code will automatically flip the visibility of the hidden image to visible at some point, what I am wondering is if there is a xaml only approach to bind the other images visibility to the opposite of the one being set to visible, with an end result of the originally visible image being collapsed and the previously collapsed image becoming visible. Don't ask why I want a xaml only approach I'm just wondering. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.  My impression is that you want an option where you don't code specifically that when controlA's property X changes that controlB's property X should be the opposite.

However you will have to write code for the IValueConverter.  The IValueConverter will work anytime you are working with the types that it handles.  The visibility of a control is not a boolean but some special enumeration, as I recall.  So you'll have to write an IValueConverter that will produce the opposite (that you seek) from the property bound value.

Another answer I helped with covered this in basic detail and may be of help to you as a guide: [Silverlight Databinding Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300013/silverlight-databinding-question/6300127#6300127).